# I want to use Lubuntu GUI instead of CLI?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, lubuntu, gui

I have installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my computer but i can only log into terminal (tty1) and not graphical mode. So i want to  install Graphical mode via terminal i tried every possible thing to make it work.I ran command like

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

But it didn't work gave an error about **broken held packages** so I installed aptitude and again ran `sudo aptitude install lubuntu-desktop`. then I upgraded updated dist-upgraded. After rebooting, I got an error **"The System running on low graphics"** so I followed [these steps](http://simpledeveloper.com/system-running-in-low-graphics-mode/).

Now no error of low graphics but still Lubuntu is in command line and whenever i press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> only black screen appears.

I am not understanding at all what's happening.

Comment: If your computer boots to a black/blank screen have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). Otherwise, the easiest is just a reinstall of Lubuntu, because sometimes you can't figure it out.

Comment: I have installed Lubuntu 14.04 almost 5 time but no desktop only tty1,tty2,tty3,tty4,tty5 & tty6 but when i press ctrl+atl+7 only a black color screen with cursor appears. How to get into GUI mode and runs it by default . I know that while installing a fresh lubuntu  by default its take graphical mode but for me it does'nt

Comment: Do you mind adding your PC specs to your post?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Fw6rqXV_FBRFliN3ZzbUNLZkE

my pc specs

Comment: Just now i have installed fresh lubuntu 14.04.5 32bit and ran cmd
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

After Ctrl + atl +f7 it shows 

*Restoring resolver state..      [OK] 

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Now waiting for your reply.

Comment: Does 14.04.5 works? And what do you mean "ran cmd"? Also, did you have a look at the post I linked?

Comment: Sorry for bad English. Do i have to select nomodeset option ??

Comment: If you are following the link, then yes.

Comment: I will try install it in nomodeset . Is there any problem with graphics drivers?

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean. Do you mean that you will have problems when you have nomodeset enabled and you try to install your graphics driver?

Comment: I  installed lubuntu 14.04.5 successfully  in nomodeset i have Graphical UI but its not in full screen ?

Comment: Hey i connected another moniter and it is working in full screen.Thank you so much .